# color ramp steps limitation

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, color, shader-nodes, color-management

I'm using the color ramp node to mapping values for later use, but the color ramp has a limitation of steps of 32, can I reset the limitation through python? or is anyway to get rid of the limitation?
[image]

There is a way, here is the solution!!! [float curve couldn't create a step function](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/314395/float-curve-couldnt-create-a-step-function/314467#314467)

Comment: Hello, baby boss, if the answers linked in the commentary are not good for you, by all means edit this post to explain why not, and we can re-open for you. If you can include some details of your use-case, maybe we can make some suggestions  of how to  achieve your purpose.. perhaps not involving a _Color Ramp_ ? The placement of all these stops looks pretty painful.

Comment: Now I get the answer from my other post question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/314395/float-curve-couldnt-create-a-step-function/314467#314467